# CKEditor - Restrict editor size to less than height of the window

Tags: css, reactjs, ckeditor5

Using CKEditor 5 with React.  I am looking for a better solution to limit the height of the editor. By default, it appears it set the height to fit the content in the editor.  In my application, the context is frequently quite large. this makes the editor go past the bottom of the screen and then the page has to be scrolled down to see more content. The consequence of scrolling, is you can then no longer see the editors toolbar.  Thus far, I have mitigated this by using a max-height in CSS.
Like the following:

```
.ck-editor__editable {
min-height: 20vw;
max-height: 37vw;
resize: both;
}
```

This works ok if the window is maximized to full screen.  However, if for example it is used on a 4K monitor, then the editor is very small.
In addition, I recently added a FullScreen plugin and the max-height attribute limits the height when the FullScreen mode is enabled.  Which make the FullScreen mode, pointless.

Therefore, I am hoping there is a better solution to size the editor so that we can control it to fill most of the height of the window, without causing the page to scroll and allow the FullScreen mode to work properly.

Any thoughts/ideas?